# chat.facebook.com connection time out error

Tags: c#, .net, facebook

I write the following code in my project.

```
TcpClient tcp = new TcpClient();
tcp.Connect("chat.facebook.com", 5222);
```

When I run my project,I got the following error.

A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 69.171.227.26:5222

Anybody advice me?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there's no firewall in place between you and chat.facebook.com which is blocking your outbound access on port 5222?

For example, I just did this:

```
$ telnet chat.facebook.com 5222
Trying 66.220.151.99...
Connected to chat.facebook.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

so it's fine for me

Comment: Can you connect to other servers on port 5222? e.g. jabber.org port 5222

Comment: I connect to local server on port 5222.But I can't connect to remote servers on port 5222.